# Angular js Accordion working in tables

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angular-ui

Hi could I ask how could i achieved accordion in this one. I spent a lot of time doing this but i couldn't seem to fix it

this is my list screenshots

[image]

it does have unique itemnumber and I want to put accordion to item that has the same first 6 digits in itemnumber like the six item in the bottom of the list (same image).

this is my html code :

```
<table class="table table-hover" id="itemlist">
            <tr>
                <th></th>
                <th>Item Number</th>
            </tr>
            <tr id="itemRowId_{{ item.Ilist.id}}" title="{{item.Ilist.itemnumber}}" data-ng-repeat-start="item in items | filter:itemSearch" draggable class="draggableItem">
                <td>
<img title="list" class="{{ item.Ilist.itemnumber }}"  id="{{ item.Ilist.itemnumber }}" width="50px" src="http:source.com{{ item.Ilist.itemnumber }}"/></td>
                <td >{{ item.Ilist.itemnumber}}</td>

            </tr>

            <tr data-ng-repeat-end></tr>
        </table>
```

and this is my json:

```
   {
        "status": "ok",
        "message": "",
        "data": [
            {
                "Ilist": {
                    "id": "1",
                    "itemnumber": "539386001"
                }
            },
            {
                "Ilist": {
                    "id": "2",
                    "itemnumber": "153443003"
                }
            },
            {
                "Ilist": {
                    "id": "3",
                    "itemnumber": "391705001"
                }
            },
            {
                "Ilist": {
                    "id": "4",
                    "itemnumber": "120143"
                }
            },
            {
                "Ilist": {
                    "id": "5",
                    "itemnumber": "154702"
                }
            },
            {
                "Ilist": {
                    "id": "6",
                    "itemnumber": "727106004"
                }
            },
            {
                "Ilist": {
                    "id": "7",
                    "itemnumber": "542699951"
                }
            },
            {
                "Ilist": {
                    "id": "8",
                    "itemnumber": "245088900071"
                }
            },
            {
                "Ilist": {
                    "id": "9",
                    "itemnumber": "245088900072"
                }
            },
            {
                "Ilist": {
                    "id": "10",
                    "itemnumber": "245088900077"
                }
            }
        ]
    }
```

please spare me, i'm new to angular,

i take my time to view this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Pixic/VGgbq/) but i don't quite follow

also this [angular accordion](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/) but i couldn't make it work on tables.

Comment: If you're just trying to get the expand/collapse animation to work: you can't animate height with table cells, only with block-level elements like `div`.

Comment: What's your Javascript code you have for that?

Comment: @JohannesJander angular js and jquery

Comment: No, I mean do you have any code you can add to the question at all?